# Ruby TK. Как начать использовать?

Tags: ruby

Пытаюсь по книге сделать пример, в котором требуется подключить tk, а выдает такое:

> /home/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require': cannot load such file -- tk (LoadError)   from
>   /home/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'   from p001hello.rb:1:in `'

Вот код, ничего особенного. Понятно, что дело именно в этом (расширении, не знаю, как правильно это называется):

```
require 'tk'

hello = TkRoot.new
TkLabel.new(hello) do
  text "\n Hello, Matz! \n"
  pack
end
Tk.mainloop
```

Comment: Насколько я знаю, чтобы заюзать TK, надо какие-то либы поставить. Но вот какие - не знаю.

Comment: Логично. Вот в том-то и проблема, где их взять и как ставить.

Comment: А что за ОС используется? У меня на ElementaryOS такая же проблема. Но я особо не копал.

Comment: Я посмотрел, там целый букет приключений с погружением в процесс сборки Ruby. В RVM поддержка этого дела долгое время была отключена из-за проблем с установкой на OS X, и по-моему, она выключена и сейчас (или пропускается в случае проблем, трудно сказать, установщик очень молчалив).

Comment: Я попробовал через RVM переустановить Ruby-2.2.2 с опциями `--with-tcl` и `--with-tk`. Долго собиралось, компилировалось, для каждого гемсета, но после переустановки так и не заработало(

Comment: У меня оно так и не нашло Tcl/Tk в системе (если зайти в папку с расширением и сделать `ruby extconf.rb`, он жалуется). Хотя всё есть, и даже совместимой версии 8.5 (с 8.6 пока несовместимо). Наталкивает на мысль, что их местоположение надо указать руками. На этом я раскопки пока прекратил.

Comment: @МАХОРКА TK разве не из коробки в Ruby?

Comment: @titov_andrei У меня нет. У автора вопроса тоже.

Comment: @MAXOPKA, да, у меня нет. Но я поиски прекратил, мне это нужно было только для примера из книги, но книга старая довольно, так что я забил и для себя взглянул на шузы.

Comment: @titov_andrei и да, и нет. Он входит в стандартную библиотеку интерпретатора, но обычно он собирается без него, т. к. используется редко, а требует довольно много.

Comment: @titov_andrei [tag:tkinter] это библиотека для Python. В этом вопросе она неуместна.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
gem install tk
```